# Hibernate max() query

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to select a records where extId == parameter i give and from those records i want the latest by date (`createDate` property). Im trying this :

```
select r from Record r where r.extId=:eid and r.createDate=(select max(r.createDate) from r where r.id=r.id)
```

simply returns latest record. Help me please.

Comment: That is what you want right ?

Comment: i want latest record from those where r.extId=:eid

Answer (score 2):

You can try this query,it works for me.

```
from Record r where r.extId=:eid and r.createDate IN (select max(r2.createDate) from Recordr2)
```

Comment: Thanks for response. What's Record2?

Comment: Sorry my mistake.use Record r2 instead of Recordr2

Comment: from Record r where r.extId=:eid and r.createDate IN (select max(r2.createDate) from Record r2)